# Error deploying a Grails 1.3.2 war on JBoss6

Tags: grails, jboss, groovy

We are trying to upgrade from JBoss 4 to JBoss 6 and receive the following error when deploying our Grails 1.3.2 war:

```
09:53:33,343 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
09:53:37,515 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA
09:53:38,000 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0]
09:53:42,515 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
09:53:52,593 WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:groovy.jmx.builder.package-info: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "groovy/jmx/builder/package-info" in class file groovy/jmx/builder/package-info
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_20]
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
                at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.resolveComplexTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:458) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:414) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.java:54) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.config.plugins.AbstractConfiguration.getTypeInfo(AbstractConfiguration.java:121) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfig.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfig.java:95) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfigurator.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfigurator.java:102) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ConfiguratorReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(ConfiguratorReflectProvider.java:47) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.CachingReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(CachingReflectProvider.java:52) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getTypeInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:60) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getClassInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:72) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:107) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.AnnotationsScanningPlugin.visit(AnnotationsScanningPlugin.java:89) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
                at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
```

Is anyone familiar with this error and how it might be worked around? My googling brings back little or no info on deploying Grails wars to JBoss 6 (we might have been premature here) and only a couple dead-ends on this specific error.

Any help appreciated.

***Edit: I originally incorrectly specified the grails version number as 1.2.3, it is actually 1.3.2***

Comment: What JDK and OS are you using?

Comment: @Victor Sergienko - JDK 1.6 and Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is relevant at all, but there were special steps required to deploy to JBoss5: http://blog.saddey.net/2010/03/06/how-to-deploy-a-grails-application-to-jboss-5/

Perhaps they are still relevant for JBoss 6 ?

Illegal class name "groovy/jmx/builder/package-info" - seems to point to other problems though. I've noticed other people having the same problem:

> http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.wiki.xwiki.user/16175
>   http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Jboss-AS-6-0-0-Grails-1-3-5-application-deployment-failure-td3019060.html

Tomcat7 apparently had this problem and was fixed in 7.0.4:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50087

> "Fixed in trunk and will be in 7.0.4
>   onwards. You'll still see the stack
>   trace (since that Groovy class has an
>   invalid name) but context deployment
>   will continue rather than failing."

Sounds like that Groovy class really does have an invalid name.

From http://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS :

> JBoss Web 3.X is a reduced web profile
>   of AS6. It is JBoss implementation of
>   the new specs. It is not based on TC7
>   but still share code with it.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I had seen some of those links too, and now looking at the second and third links you have here makes me think perhaps the current JBoss 6 release merged some bad Tomcat < 7.0.4 code into the JBoss Web 3.X fork and is hopeless without a similar patch. Perhaps I should file a bug with the JBoss folks...